# Where does this proof of convergence fail?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Given the series, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{n}{n+1}$$

I know we can immediately conclude that it is obviously divergent by the divergence test. But I want to know where exactly am I going wrong in the following 'proof' as I have just started learning about convergence and divergence.

Here is what I did :

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1} & = \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3}\right)+\left(-\frac{3}{4} + \frac{4}{5}\right)+\left(-\frac{5}{6} + \frac{6}{7}\right)+\dots \\
& = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{42} + \dots\\
& = \frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{6\cdot 7}+\dots \\ 
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\left(\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 8}+\dots\right) \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}- \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right)\\
& =3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+2)(2n+1)(2n+2)},\end{align}
and this last series obviously converges by the comparison test.

I am able to represent this **divergent** sum as the difference of two **convergent** sums. Where is my flaw?

Comment: The problem is that, even thought you put $\infty$ on top of the sum, you only proved that the partial sums of an even number of terms is convergent. Do a similar computation but for partial sums of an odd number of terms.

Comment: What we can immediately rule out that it is convergent because the terms do not tend to $0$. But "oscillating" is a possibility that has to be considered.

Comment: Check out Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem.

Comment: @D.B. There is no rearrangement here, this is not a conditionally convergent series.

Comment: Right, my apologies.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n\,n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}\to 1-\log(2)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\frac{(-1)^n\,n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}-\frac{2N+1}{2(N+1)}\to -\log(2)$$

So, the even partial sums tend to $1-\log(2)$ while the odd partial sums tend to $-\log(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$s_m
=\sum_{n=1}^{} (-1)^{n}\frac{n}{n+1}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
s_{2m}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2m} (-1)^{n}\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} ((-1)^{2n-1}\frac{2n-1}{2n-1+1}+(-1)^{2n}\frac{2n}{2n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (-\frac{2n-1}{2n}+\frac{2n}{2n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{-(2n-1)(2n+1)+4n^2}{2n(2n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{-(4n^2-1)+4n^2}{2n(2n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}\\
\text{and}\\
s_{2m+1}
&=s_{2m}+(-1)^{2m+1}\frac{2m+1}{2m+2}\\
&=s_{2m}-\frac{2m+1}{2m+2}\\
&=s_{2m}-(1-\frac{1}{2m+2})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
the even terms converge to
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}
$
and the odd terms converge to
$-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}
$.

Therefore the series
does not converge.